# Is there a bug in spriteKit that causes animations to think they're running and aren't?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I thought I was just doing something wrong, but I've gone through my code hundreds of times, and it seems like it should work just fine.

Basically I have an empty sprite in a specific space. I want to change the position of that sprite to out of frame, change its texture, and then animate it back where it was.

Here is my code:

```
func animateNewShape(newShape: Shape, completion: () -> ()) {
    let newShapeSprite = level.shapeAtColumn(newShape.column, row: newShape.row)?.sprite
    let enterSpriteDuration = 2.0
    let spriteEnterAction = SKAction.moveTo(pointForColumn(newShape.column, row: newShape.row), duration: enterSpriteDuration)
    let newShapeSpriteTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: (ShapeType(rawValue: randomShapeType)?.spriteName)!)




    switch lastSwipeDirection {
    case 1:
        newShapeSprite!.position = CGPointMake(pointForColumn(newShape.column, row: newShape.row).x, pointForColumn(newShape.column, row: newShape.row).y-500)
        print(newShapeSprite?.position)
    case 2:
        newShapeSprite!.position = CGPointMake(pointForColumn(newShape.column, row: newShape.row).x-100, pointForColumn(newShape.column, row: newShape.row).y)
        print(newShapeSprite?.position)
    case 3:
        newShapeSprite!.position = CGPointMake(pointForColumn(newShape.column, row: newShape.row).x, pointForColumn(newShape.column, row: newShape.row).y+500)
        print(newShapeSprite?.position)
    case 4:
        newShapeSprite!.position = CGPointMake(pointForColumn(newShape.column, row: newShape.row).x+100, pointForColumn(newShape.column, row: newShape.row).y)
        print(newShapeSprite?.position)
    default:
        print("DO NOT READ THIS")
    }



    newShape.sprite = newShapeSprite
    newShapeSprite?.texture = newShapeSpriteTexture
    print("Going to move from \(newShapeSprite?.position) to \(spriteEnterAction)")
    newShapeSprite!.runAction(spriteEnterAction, completion: completion)
}
```

This code works fine in every situation except when a new shape is supposed to appear where an old one was. For example, if there was a shape at (0,0) and I move the sprite up one to (1,0), the new piece should come up from out of frame and end up at (0,0). This happens maybe 50% of the time the way it should. The other half of the time the sprite just appears in place with no animation. The completion still says it hasn't finished, and the print statement shows the correct off screen position, but there is no animation. It's there before the piece going from (0,0) to (0,1) is finished animating. I can't find any pattern as to when it happens, just seems completely random. Sometimes it animates perfectly, other times it appears.

Is this some kind of spriteKit bug? Or is my code messed up in some way? I would really appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: Just on the off chance, have you checked the `zPosition` property?

Comment: I haven't set the zPosition at all, but would that effect anything? The problem is the sprite just appearing in place instead of animating to the place like it should.

Comment: You have an animated gif of this in action?  Was curious as you mentioned this issue happened on overlapping nodes, 50% of the time. The same `zPosition` for overlapping nodes can create unpredictable rendering results.